# Enabling CodeIgniter logging in Ubuntu

Tags: codeigniter, logging, ubuntu

I'm trying to enable logging for CodeIgniter in Ubuntu. However, nothing seems to be written in my `application/logs` directory. Here's what I've done so far...

In the controller `login.php`, I have the following lines:

```
public function index(){
    log_message("error", "Logging sanity check.");
}
```

I set it to `error` just to make sure it gets logged no matter what. Then, in my `config.php`, I set `log_threshold` to 3 (just to be safe).

Then, in the terminal running as superuser, I do `chmod 666 logs` and `chown root logs`.

Now no matter how many times I visit `index.php/login`, nothing seems to get logged. I've tried that both in a browser ran as superuser and as normal user. All I get in `application/logs` is an `index.html` which displays "Directory access is forbidden." I've even tried resetting XAMPP. What have I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache on ubuntu doesn't run as `root`, that's for one. Secondly, directory permissions must be `rwx`, which equals to 7. So you have two options:

1) Relax writing permissions for everyone on the logs dir with `chmod 777 logs`, or
2) `chown` the directory to the user that's running apache (`apache`)

Comment: I don't understand...I need execute priveleges on `logs`? I since I'd only be reading and writing logs, I thought I'd only need that so I used `chmod 666 logs`.

Comment: Directories need execute privileges by default.